# Нормально ли, если сборщик мусора вызывается часто?

Tags: c#

В моей программе я наблюдаю в средствах диагностики, что сборщик мусора вызывается очень часто, на скриншоте это видно желтыми флажками. Возможно это замедляет работу моей программы.
Просто у меня много событий с сервера, в которых создаются временные переменные и объекты. Поэтому, как я понимаю, сборщик их убирает так часто, есть ли смысл эти переменные создавать глобально?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Смотря что именно он собирает. Если это сборка 0-го поколения - то все ок, работу это не замедляет, и это нормально - вы же выделяете объекты, лучше если они быстро будут умирать, чем если они будут жить слишком долго и память будет течь.

Comment: @PashaPash все сборки мусора 1-го поколения. Можно ли как-нибудь отследить, что именно он сбрасывает, чтобы исправить это в коде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое - это вычислить аллокации в коде. Аллокация нового объекта выполняется с помощью ключевого слова `new`. Меньше аллокаций - меньше потом собирать.

Переиспользование созданных объектов может помочь. Обратите внимание на максимально часто выполняемый код, скорее всего мусора создается больше всего там.

Для более глубокого анализа могут пригодится профилирование процессора и памяти.